# How to create several dynamic listview Unknown number of listveiw

Tags: c#, listview

In my project I need to create several lisview dinamically, I have a array with some value `string[] = array{"BILL", "ORDER", "DELEVERY FORM", "RCL", "ESTIMATION", ...}`; And I would like create a listview to each value from array.

```
void CreateListView(string[] array)
{
    foreach(value in array)
    {
                ListView listView[value] = new ListView();
                this.Controls.Add(listView[value]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need multiple ListViews?...or do you want multiple ListViewItems (columns) in an existing ListView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you want to create the listviews and name them according to the given array. If that is the case, then this should satisfy.

```
    void CreateListView(string[] array)
    {
        foreach (var value in array)
        {
            ListView listView = new ListView {Name = value};
            Controls.Add(listView);

        }
    }
```